# Chromecast Receiver App - Media state changed: time_progress event

Tags: chromecast

When testing my Receiver app and watching the console, I see a line created by cast_receiver.js that says:

```
[  3.034s] [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia] Media state changed: time_progress=false
```

Eventually, when the video is playing, I get a message that says:

```
[  3.034s] [cast.receiver.RemoteMedia] Media state changed: time_progress=true
```

Is there an event I can monitor from the RemoteMedia API that will allow me to tie in to this 'time_progress' event?  I am trying to hide and show a loader when the video is loading. Currently i show and hide the loader based on the 'timeupdate' event from the video element, however, this event has proven to not be reliable for me.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Rather than trying to attach to the the status message above, you will be better off just attaching to the `playing` event for the [video media element](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/video#Media_Events).

Comment: I tried this before, and just tested again to be sure.  The video element 'playing' event fires as soon as the video begins loading, but it still takes a while for the video to play.  I am currently listening to the 'timeupdate' event and removing the loader once the 'timeupdate' changes for the first time.  The problem is that sometimes a video will load and play the first frame, and then go back to loading again, so my loader is gone, but the video is still loading.  Only thing I have seen that accurately shows when the video is playing, and not, is the time_progress message.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

On the sender side, you will get status update if time_progress changes. On the receiver side, you can't directly register to be notified if time_progress is updated but there are ways around that if it is absolutely needed. As Les mentioned, listening on the video element's events is the best way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Mike, I had a similar issue at one point and I used a counter inside the time_update listener to basically keep track of how many times time_update has been called before removing the spinner. Generally I found that 2-4 calls and then you can be sure that the video is playing. Once the counter reaches it's goal then I remove the listener from within the listener. The downside is you have to reattach the listener anytime the video pauses, etc.

Comment: Thank you.  I am now rounding the current time from the 'timeupdate' event to the nearest 10th of a decimal and comparing it with the last 'timeupdate' current time (rounded as well) and this seems to be working, but ultimately, is a work-around for the video player events not firing at the correct time.  I would still prefer an actual video player event, but this will have to do unless I hear from someone who has figured this out.